# Efficiently inserting values into a map. Better incrementing or decrementing keys?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of  pairs ordered by key in decrementing order.
I want to efficiently transform it to a map.
This is what I currently do:

```
int size = vect.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    map[vect[i].key] = vect[i];
```

Is there a point in traversing the vector backwards and inserting values with lowest keys first? I'm not sure how insert works internally and whether it even matters...

How about using map constructor and just passing the vector into that instead of looping? This would be recreating the map, vs doing map.clear() that I currently do between runs.

I read a few other SO answers about [key]=val being about the same as insert() but none deal with insertion order.

Comment: I don't think this will cause a major performance impact...

Comment: You should try `std::map::insert(position, pair)` where `position` is either `begin()` or `end()` as appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean `vect[i].first` and if so do you really want `std::map<Key, pair<Key,Value>>` rather than `std::map<Key,Value>`? If the latter is OK then the optimum way to populate it from an already sorted range is `Map map(vect.begin(), vect.end());`

Comment: And if the latter isn't OK, then the optimum way is still to use the constructor that takes two iterators, but use a `boost::transform_iterator` (or your own hand-crafted equivalent) to pass the funny `pair<Key, pair<Key, Value>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` is usually implemented as [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). Therefore, it doesn't really matter whether you increment or decrement the keys. It will still perform a search with [O(log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity and rebalancing.

What you can do to speed up your insertion is use either [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) or [emplace_hint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) with "hint", which is an iterator used as a suggestion as to where to insert the new element.

Constructing map with a range won't make a difference.

It is hard to recommend the best data structure for you without knowing details about the program  and data it handles. Generally, RB-tree is the best you can get for general case (and that's why it is an implementation of choice for `std::map`).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the details, yes a red-black tree backing it is probably good enough for what I'm doing either way then. I will look at emplace_hint as an optimization, since I know the insertion order.

Comment: Constructing with a range _does_ make a difference if the range is already sorted. If each insertion happens after the previous one then there is no need to perform a lookup to find the right position for each element.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yes, that would be an equivalent to `insert(end(), X)`. I guess what I meant is that constructor doesn't magically speed things up in a way you can't achieve with insertion after the construction.

Answer (score 2):

I decided this was interesting enough (an outright bug in the standard that lasted 13 years) to add as an answer.

[Section 23.1.2 of the C++03 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/lib-containers.html#lib.associative.requirements) says, concerning the "hinted" version `insert(p,t)`, that the complexity is:

> logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if **t** is inserted right after **p**

What this means is that if you insert `n` elements in *sorted* order, providing the correct hint each time, then the total time will be `O(n)`, not `O(n log n)`. Even though some individual insertions will take logarithmic time, the average time per insertion will still be constant.

C++11 finally fixed the wording to read "right before **p**" instead of "right after **p**", which is almost certainly what was meant in the first place... And the corrected wording actually makes it possible to use the "hint" when inserting elements in either forward or reverse order (i.e. passing `container.end()` or `container.begin()` as the hint).

Comment: It was always possible to use a hint, because implementations tended to do the right thing irrespective of what the standard said

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yeah, that's kind of what I was thinking with "...almost certainly what was meant in the first place". They would have been reluctant to change it in C++11 otherwise, I suspect. What I do not understand is how it could survive through the C++03 process if all of the implementations did "the right thing" already. Surely _some_ implementor actually read C++98 (?)

Comment: The problem was known as early as 2000, but it wasn't clear what the right fix was. [LWG 233](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#233) and [N1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html) have some of the history.  It's a bit misleading to say the defect lasted 13 years, when it was fixed in the draft sooner than 2011, there just wasn't a new standard published before then that could have included the fix.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for those references. Reading them carefully, it seems like the issue of how to interpret the "hint" for multiset/multimap (which is debatable) got mixed up with this issue (which is not). As a result, this fairly obvious bug fix slipped through the cracks until C++11.